# Fill a vector with alphabet chars using std::generate_n

Tags: c++, stl

I want to fill a vector with the letters of the alphabet. So I wrote the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

char i='a';
char f(){return i++;};

int main()
{

  std::vector<char> lol(24);

  std::generate_n(lol.begin(),lol.size(),f);

  std::copy(lol.begin(),lol.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,","));

}
```

But std::copy prints `97,98,99...` the ASCII codes of the letters. How can I fix this?

Comment: By the way, look up `std::iota` and realize that letters do not have to be contiguous in the character execution set.

Comment: @chris Thank you very much, it's much easier with this way `std::iota(lol.begin(),lol.end(),'a');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the template specialization to char  :`std::copy(lol.begin(),lol.end(),std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout,","));`

Answer (score 2):

Your ostream_iterator is `<int>` instead of `<char>` - Try changing it to `<char>`